# How to trigger default magento validation in custom module in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, requirejs, form-validation, product-review

**I have created custom module for magento review module, Now All the functionalities works fine. But default magento validation is failed for Review form. Now, How do i trigger the dafault validation to my custom module**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add this `data-hasrequired=" Required Fields"  data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'` line to your form tag as show in below example and need to set validation class in input element like `data-validate='{}'`

```
<form id="test" name="test" method="post"  action="<?php echo $block->getUrl('test/index/test'); ?>" data-hasrequired="* Required Fields"  data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
    <div class="input-box">
         <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo __('First name / last name'); ?>" value="" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" data-validate='{"required":true}'>
         </div>
    </form>
```

**For fore info please follow this links**
http://inchoo.net/magento-2/validate-custom-form-in-magento-2/

Comment: Thanks for your response. Validation is worked for other fields except star rating

Comment: I need to validate including star rating in Review module

Comment: For that you have to add custom validation and validate

Comment: I have overrided the form.phtml from Magento\Review\view\frontend\templates\form.phtml to my custom module. Then, Why do I need to do custom validation for star rating. Can you help me if i am wrong

Comment: Validation for star rating is come from in Magento Review module."Magento_Review/js/validate-review"

Comment: How u override ? please share code

Comment: you can override in theme

Comment: For Validation can u please mark my answare as right ?

Comment: I have done that already. Only I need to trigger for star rating

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71956/discussion-between-sri-and-navin-bhudiya).